# Is $A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$ a 1d or 2d manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose the set  $A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| \leq 1 \} $.
Can A be a 1d or 2d or n-dimentional manifold ?

My thought is that we can write A as $A=A_1\cup A_2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x|| < 1 \} \cup \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||=1 \}$ and cover A with the charts:

For $A_1$: $f:A_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-||(x,y)||}$ 
For $A_2$: The stereographic projection $f_N:A_1-\{(0,1)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_S:A_1-\{(0,-1)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

So it is a 1d manifold but it can't be a 2d manifold because there can not be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to a subset of $A_2$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) about manifolds with boundaries.

Comment: So it is a 2d manifold with boundary?. But is it a smooth manifold?

Comment: yes and yes (can take the exponential map for the boundary (need $2$ charts), if you only look at the interior you can just take the identity map

Comment: ok thanks!. for the standard definition of a manifold, can we say it is a 1d manifold with the above charts and not a n dimentional manifold for $n \geq 2 $

Comment: it's not a 1d manifold by any definition I know of